# React memo components and re-render when passing function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memo

Suppose I have these React components:

```
const Compo1 = ({theName}) => {
  return (
    <Nested foo={() => console.log('Dr. ' + theName)}/>
  );
};

const Compo2 = ({theName}) => {
  function theFoo() {
    console.log('Dr. ' + theName);
  }
  return (
    <Nested foo={theFoo}/>
  );
};
```

And the nested component, wrapped in [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```
const Nested = React.memo(({foo}) => {
  return (
    <Button onClick={foo}>Click me</Button>
  );
});
```

Function passed in `foo` is [always recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10204420) in `Compo1` and also `Compo2`, correct?

If so, since `foo` receives a new function every time, does it mean `memo` will be useless, thus `Nested` will always be re-rendered?

Answer (score 18):

You can use new hooks Api(React >= 16.8) to avoid recreating callback func.

Just using useCallback hook for this.

For e.g

**Parent component**

```
import React, { useCallback} from 'react';

const ParentComponent = ({theName}) => {
  const theFoo = () => {
    console.log('Dr. ' + theName);
  }

  const memoizedCallback = useCallback(theFoo , []);

  return (
     <Nested foo={memoizedCallback}/>
   );
};
```

useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed (which passed in the second argument) 
In this case we pass **empty array** as dependencies and therefore the function will be created only once.

**And nested component:**

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Nested = ({foo}) => (
  <Button onClick={foo}>Click me</Button>
);

export default memo(Nested);
```

For more info - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: It seems to me you should be passing `theName` in the dependency array then. Otherwise if `theName` changes in your parent component, the `onClick` listener will still have the old value

Answer (score 1):

The `memo` function will shallow compare every different props, including functions. However, by redefining your function inside your components in every render, you will create a different reference every time, triggering a re-render.

Although, as your can see in `Comp3`, you can still use memo and avoid re-rendering by declaring an external function :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        setInterval(() => { this.setState({ e: true }) }, 2000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Compo1 />
                <Compo2 />
                <Compo3 />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Compo1 = () => <Nested foo={() => console.log('Comp1 rendering')} />

const Compo2 = () => {
    function theFoo() {
        console.log('Comp2 rendering');
    }
    return <Nested foo={theFoo} />
};

const foo3 = function (text) { console.log('Comp3 rendering ' + text) }

const Compo3 = () => <Nested foo={foo3} />

const Nested = React.memo(({ foo }) => {
    foo('a param')
    return <div />
})


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Comment: What if you have to pass arguments to this external function?

Comment: What if the argument is a derivation from the received props? I updated my question to reflect this situation.

Comment: You will not be able to change how the function behaves directly. You can alwasy pass what you want when calling the function though.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way I found was to use `useRef`. Specifically I use this structure together with Formik to prevent re-rendering of a long list of input values.

```js
const MyMemoizedGroupList = React.memo(
  ({
    groups,
    arrayHelpersRef,
  }) => {
    // [..] stuff
  }
}

function MainComponent() {
  const groupsArrayHelpersRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <Formik 
      // [..] stuff
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="groups"
            render={arrayHelpers => {
              groupsArrayHelpersRef.current = arrayHelpers;
            }}
          />
          <MyMemoizedGroupList 
            groups={values.groups} 
            arrayHelpersRef={groupsArrayHelpersRef} 
          /> 
          {/* [..] stuff */}
        </Form>
      )} 
    />
  );
}
```